# Problem checking if a file in a loop is a directory

Tags: bash, directory

This code is a working example of checking if a path is a directory:

```
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        printf "Directory exists\n"
else
        printf "Does not exists\n"
fi
```

I changed it to this to try and test if files in a directory are directories or not:

```
for file in "$1/*"; do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then 
                printf "Directory: %s\n" $file
        else
                printf "File: %s\n" $file
        fi  
done
```

But it does not work - directories are displayed as if they were files. Why wont it work? And how can I get this code to do what I want?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't quote the asterisk.

```
for file in "$1"/* ; do
```

Comment: Wow that was quick, and works too :) Apparently I still have to wait 12 minutes to mark this as solved. Thanks.